# Javascript / PHP Add Checkbox Values to Input Text

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, checkbox

I have a Loop with checkbox values from database and when I check some box I need that the value passes to the input (without submit button);

```
<?php

        while($row = $sth->fetch()) {

              echo("<input type='checkbox' value='".$row['name']."'>".$row['name']."</option>");
        }
        echo('<input type="text" name="modelos" />');

?>
```

Thanks

Comment: markup is not right you /option> at the end ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(){
    var options="";
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function(){
        options += $(this).val()+";"; 
    });

    $("input[name='modelos']").val(options);
});
```

**Online demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZPxqJ/6/

Comment: Yes, is this that I want, but I need all values that I check the input, for example: name1 ; name2 ; name3

Answer (score 0):

add a button and the following snippet

```
$("input[name=mybutton]").click(function(){
    $("input[name='modelos']").val($(":checkbox:checked").val());
});
```