# Change text input value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox, input

I'm making a newsletter contact form, and in that form the user can check the subjects they want to receive newsletters from.

I want to make a text input where its value will be the value of all the checked boxes, separated with commas.

e.g.: retails, news, manufacturing

I want it to be dynamically, when the user checks a box it appears on the text input at the same moment, and when the user uncheck the box, it desappear at the same moment too, so I think jQuery is the easiest way, I just don't know how to do it.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: So where did you get stuck when you first made a start?

Comment: I know how to make it to get just one check box value, but not getting a lot of them and separated with commas

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Do you have some code that you've worked on that's related to this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Add Multiple Check Action Values (of Checkboxes) to Input Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26727045/jquery-add-multiple-check-action-values-of-checkboxes-to-input-text)

Comment: Sorry, I really searched for the solution before asking but couldn't find it. But yes, it is duplicate :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this? (see [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/8df9sxuk/2/))

```
$('input').on('change', function(){
   var res = "";

   $('input:checked').each(function(){
       res += $(this).val()+", ";
   });

   res = res.slice(0,-2);
   $('#result').text(res);
});
```

Comment: With the necessary adaptations it worked like a charm! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.check').on('change', function() {
        var displayVal = '';
        $('.check:checked').each(function() {
            displayVal += $(this).val() + ', ';
        });
        displayVal = displayVal.slice(0,-2);
        $('.display').val(displayVal);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="blue"/> blue<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="red"/> red<br/>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" value="white"/> white<br/>
<br/>
<input type="text" class="display" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#my-form').on('change', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function(){
    var vals = [];
    $('#my-form').find('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function(){
         if($(this).checked())){
             vals.push($(this).val());
         }
    });
    $('#my-input').val(vals.join(', '));
});
```

-- for example

Comment: I see what you did and unsderstand it, but unfortunately it didn't worked to me, I don't know why, but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The following will return a string with the values of all checked boxes separated by commas.

```
var allChecked = $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').map(function(){
    return this.value
}).get().join(', ');
```